# why res.users in more modules?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

in openerp 7 i checked some modules and saw that res_users class exists in more modules.ex : survey.py...
what is the usage of that.they call it by same name

```
class res_users(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "res.users"
    _name = "res.users"
    _columns = {
        'survey_id': fields.many2many('survey', 'survey_users_rel', 'uid', 'sid', 'Groups'),
    }

res_users()
```

I need to create my own user module.then can i use like above.?
I need to save records in res_users table because seems openerp match username and password from that table.please advice me to implement this requirement.

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In survey.py, They are just adding one new field by inheriting users table. If you will use it like above by inheriting, it will add fields in the same OpenERP users table whatever you will create. I can only suggest that You can create a new table for this and change the code as per your requirements as I don't know much regarding it.